# Access individual string parameters (UIAlertView otherButtonTitles)

Tags: ios, nsstring, uialertview

I'm writing my own custom alert view for an application. The customer has their own look/feel for alert type messages. I've read that subclassing `UIAlertView` isn't really a good idea, so I'm just trying to make the current message view I'm using a bit more dynamic so I can reuse it a bit more.

Ok, my question. I am stealing the init from `UIAlertView` to init my own custom alert.

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
```

This was taken right out of Apple's `UIAlertView` initializer. Mine is going to work just the same, so why not just use their init.

I want to be able to pass in multiple strings for `otherButtonTitles`, much like `UIAlertView`. My question is, how do I access the strings being passed in?

Comment: Search for "variadic functions" in Objective-C.

Comment: That did the trick. Found this to be helpful. http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html Also shows me that making nice methods for other devs requires more work on my end. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would may the `otherButtonTitles` argument a NSArray instead of an NSString. From there you can dynamically generate additional buttons based on the count of the array, and set the title of said button to the NSString stored in current index of the array.

**EDIT:** I think I've found something promising, in UIAlertView.m (not sure if it's actually from Apple) but it takes otherButtonTitles as a string as well. It uses a `va_list` to store the otherButtonTitles, and then add's the objects to a mutable array that contains all the buttons, including the cancel button at index 0 (if applicable).

https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon/blob/master/UIKit/Classes/UIAlertView.m

Here's an excerpt:

```
 if (otherButtonTitles) {
        [self addButtonWithTitle:otherButtonTitles];

        id buttonTitle = nil;
        va_list argumentList;
        va_start(argumentList, otherButtonTitles);

        while ((buttonTitle=(__bridge NSString *)va_arg(argumentList, void *))) {
            [self addButtonWithTitle:buttonTitle];
        }

        va_end(argumentList);
    }
```

Comment: I could do that, but would like to know how Apple pulls it off. I plan on making this available to other projects, so it would be nice to mimic UIAlertView initialization that people are familiar with.

Comment: @BillBurgess I see, I'll look into it. Not making any promises though :)

Comment: Thanks. I can cop out and make it an array, but curious myself and I couldn't find anything showing how they access those strings.